# How to fix servo motor broken by wrong polarity

Tags: arduino, power, motor, servo, polarity

I accidentally plugged in my servo with the wrong polarity (with the order of wires being signal, ground and power). It immediately started releasing the 'magic smoke', but I managed to unplug it before 4-5 seconds had elapsed.

I don't think the smoke was due to the gears grinding together (that wouldn't match intuition anyway), but actually because of the electronics screwing up (too much current through a component?). So my (edited) question is: can the servo 'motor' be salvaged and converted into a DC one (the various methods for doing so described on Google)?

Googling didn't lead me to any answers, and I'm too much of a n00b to figure this out on my own. I apologize if the question is based on wrong assumptions of mine or or doesn't really ask anything objective.

Comment: You screwed up and broke it.  It's junk now.  Toss it, learn from this, and move on.  Any time spent agonizing of this is just more waste.  Get a new one and move on.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Damn. I hadn't gotten an extra one (13-year olds buying on their own don't exactly have an accommodating budget). Oh well :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fix is to throw it out and get a new one.  Seriously.  Those things need the magic smoke to operate (that's why it's magic).  Without the smoke they don't work.

Comment: Might even want to verify that the Arduino still works before counting on it.

Comment: @ScottSeidman - Naaah, I'd chuck the arduino too, just to be sure.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I did and (thankfully!) it works.

Comment: @JohnU Since the servos were powered with an external source and the only connections to the Arduino were the signal wire and the common ground. Was your comment just cheap humor, or serious also? I don't see how the Arduino could be affected (sorry if I'm looking dumb, I'm a n00b at this stuff)...

Comment: @David I see. So now I can open up the servo w/o the fear of screwing it up even more. Could you explain a bit more about what exactly was wrong?

Comment: Or rather wait, I'll Google it. Don't want to get LMGTFY'd (we n00bs eventually _do_ learn ;)...

Comment: @YatharthROCK  If you hook it up backwards then all bets are off.  It could have sent a "high" voltage back through the signal wire into the CPU and fried it.  By "high", I mean if you were running the servo off of a higher voltage than what the CPU is using.

Comment: @YatharthROCK  I wouldn't fear screwing it up even more.  It's plenty screwed.  Just crack the thing open.  Use a brick and smash it if you have to.  Then you can see how it is constructed, for next time.

Comment: 10x a lot for your answer and comments. I remember waiting for mice and keyboards to break so I could get my hands on them :)

Comment: @DavidKessner That tool is called a screwdriver where I come from. It's a brick in your part of the world, eh? ;-)

Comment: Wait, you people wait for things to break before taking them apart? I think the only thing I own which I haven't taken apart is my phone (and that's just because there are already teardowns of it on the net).

Comment: So is it smoke from the gears or like the electronics screwing up? Seems like the latter to me...

Comment: @ConnorWolf Well, I _am_ 13 and (not entirely baselessly), we aren't exactly trusted to know or care about putting the things back together... ;)

Comment: @AnindoGhosh How curious. It's like British and American English: both the countries are divided by a common language...

Comment: ...with British being the correct version.

And I was semi-serious because I genuinely believe Arduinos encourage bad habits / sloppy thinking / no thinking at all.

Comment: In case I need to protect, can I add just a low drop diode to VCC pin of servo motor?

Answer (score 2):

The servo has 3 electrical components: motor, feedback resistor and control board. Most likely, only the control board has been destroyed. So you can install a new control board and the servo will work again.

Of course, the servos are so cheap nowdays that AFAIK no one sells just control boards. But you can try "openservo": http://openservo.com/ConstructionTutorial . However, the openservo has a different control protocol (I2C) which I would not recommend for the beginners, plus openservo control board is quite expensive.

Comment: Hmmm...I have access to a PCB printer. Would that work? I don't give a damn about the servo anymore (it was a cheap one anyway), but it would be a good restoration project.

Comment: You will have to make PCB, the buy all the parts and solder them. Or you can buy pre-made openservo board (such as http://www.karlssonrobotics.com/cart/openservo/). Just make sure you read the openservo forums first, and that you are comfortable with installing and debugging openservo board.

Comment: If you want to learn how a servo works, you could go through the exercise of wiring up the motor and feedback pot from the dead servo to the Arduino (use an H-bridge to drive the motor, connect the pot to an analog input) and write a feedback loop program to control it all.

Comment: @jwygralak Hmm... keeping track of the position of the servo to accept position values instead of movement values is what you're saying, right? I'll try that to...